# extract text from span with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some LinkedIn data and I would like to grab the text inside this span within a for loop. So the below would return a string = "2 shared connections"

```
<span class="search-result__social-proof-count Sans-13px-black-55%-semibold text-align-left ml1">
      2 shared connections
    </span>
```

And here is the xpath:

```
//*[@id="ember4490"]/span
```

So far I am able to select the span correctly with this code:

```
mutual_conns_with_text = div.find('span', {'class': 'search-result__social-proof-count Sans-13px-black-55%-semibold text-align-left ml1'})
```

However, the above selects the entire span NOT **just the text**. And the code below throws an exception:

```
mutual_conns_with_text = div.find('span', {'class': 'search-result__social-proof-count Sans-13px-black-55%-semibold text-align-left ml1'}).getText()
```

the exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Comment: Your question has contradictory information in it. On the one hand you say `div.find('span', {'class': 'search-result__social-proof-count Sans-13px-black-55%-semibold text-align-left ml1'})` returns a `span`, but on the other hand, the `AttributeError` implies that the same expression is returning `None`. They both can't be true.

Comment: I think you missed a detail. There is .getText() at the end of the one that is throwing the exception.

Comment: The exception occurs because the `div.find(...)` is returning `None`. So you are essentially evaluating `None.getText()`. Since `None` does not have a `getText` attribute, an `AttributeError` is raised.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply ask for the `text` attribute of the `span` element:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> HTML = '''\
... <span class="search-result__social-proof-count Sans-13px-black-55%-semibold text-align-left ml1">
...     2 shared connection
... </span>'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> mutual_conns_with_text = soup.find('span', {'class': 'search-result__social-proof-count Sans-13px-black-55%-semibold text-align-left ml1'})
>>> mutual_conns_with_text.text
'\n\t2 shared connection\n'
```